# SQL Outer Joins with count function

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I was writing a query that gets me all users. Every user can have a picture and every user can like that picture once.

There are 3 tables:
User
Picture
Like

So I need all user data with the like count of their picture and I want to get it in just 1 query. I used right join to get also the users which don't have a picture and a left join for the users which don't have likes. Now I have all infos I need except the likes. When I count now I always get 1 count even when there are no likes. Is it possible in 1 query because I also need to order by likes ?

Here is my query.

```
SELECT u.uid,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       email,
       zipcode,
       city,
       street,
       Count(*) AS likes
FROM   picture p
       RIGHT JOIN USER u using(pid)
       JOIN like using(uid)
GROUP  BY uid,
          firstname,
          lastname,
          email,
          zipcode,
          city,
          street;
```

Edit:

This query is correct:

```
SELECT u.uid, firstname, lastname, email, zipcode, city, street, count(L.PID) as likes 
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Like L USING(PID) 
GROUP BY uid,firstname,lastname,email,zipcode,city,street;
```

Comment: Look in to the differences between `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(like.uid)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT like.uid)`

Comment: The table structure would be nice, since it looks like you may have an issue with your join to `like` as written. At first glance, it would appear that you're actually counting the number of times a user has "liked" a picture and not the number of times that **his** picture was liked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table structure would be nice, since it looks like you may have an issue with your join to `like` as written. At first glance, it would appear that you're actually counting the number of times a user has "liked" a picture and not the number of times that **his** picture was liked. In any case, it's reasonable to assume that it must be a user that likes something, so the user ID in the `like` table refers to the person that's doing the liking and not what's being liked.

I'll assume here that `like` is a join table with foreign keys `User.uid` and `Picture.pid`. If this is not the case, edit the question to be more clear and I'll alter accordingly.

If you're trying to get all users (plus other information about them), it's more clear what you're trying to do if you start with that, so it's best if the `FROM` clause is `User u` and work from there:

```
SELECT
  u.uid,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  email,
  zipcode,
  city,
  street,
  Count(*) AS 'likes'
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Like l ON u.pid = l.pid
GROUP BY
  u.uid,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  email,
  zipcode,
  city,
  street
```

Comment: Thank you, nice answer. I didn't need the join on picture. And it works now like a charm. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Count something from the Like table, ex:

```
SELECT u.uid, firstname,lastname,email,zipcode,city,street
     , count(L.UID) as likes 
FROM Picture p 
RIGHT JOIN User u 
    using(PID) 
LEFT JOIN Like L
    USING(UID) 
GROUP BY uid,firstname,lastname,email,zipcode,city,street;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly. The only thing is that it shows me how many likes the user has made and not how many likes his picture has. :D

Comment: You can correct your answer and I'll mark it as correct. ;)